# I was trying to make a discord bot when I got an intents error

Tags: python

So I was trying to make a discord bot using discord.py, but when i run it I get an intents error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 4, in <module> client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ',') TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'`

Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ',')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Discord.py is working fine')

client.run('OTk4OTY4ODkyMTI0ODI3NzA4.GYacQE.wNuzbPUBd5S1W2UhgxP2NOheyqLR248VPMdkzU')
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: You need to do what the error told you to do:  Add the `intents` keyword argument to the call to `commands.Bot`.  So it would look like `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=xxx)` for whatever `xxx` makes sense for your application.

Comment: What exactly will I put in place of xxx for a bot

Comment: I think intents were new to version 1.5.  Older examples don't use them, but now they seem to be required.  You're going to need to read the documentation, such as [A Primer to Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

this worked for me
they have set up new intents mechanism for security dont forget to enable privileged intents in the discord dev portal